# Git merge and select local file in conflicts

Tags: python, git

I have an flask project which I have deployed to openshift, which I maintain locally. I deleted it from openshift and now would like to redeploy it. In the openshift gui, I created the a python app and grabbed the openshift git repo;

```
 ssh://*******@myproject.rhcloud.com/~/git/myproject.git/
```

I changed origin to the new url with:

```
git remote set-url origin ssh://*******@myproject.rhcloud.com/~/git/myproject.git/
```

Now  based on https://developers.openshift.com/en/knowledge-base.html#sync-a-new-git-repo-with-an-existing-git-repo I want to pull and merge.

I tried:

```
$ git pull ssh://*******@myproject.rhcloud.com/~/git/myproject.git/               

From ssh://*******@myproject.rhcloud.com/~/git/myproject.git/
 * branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
Auto-merging wsgi.py
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in wsgi.py
Auto-merging .openshift/markers/README.md
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in .openshift/markers/README.md
Auto-merging .openshift/cron/README.cron
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in .openshift/cron/README.cron
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

Basically at this point If I understand correctly, I want to choose my local files over the remote files in all cases. What is the best way to do this.

I'm suspecting a rebase may be in order but not sure.

Comment: Open up the files (README.md, README.cron) and fix the merges and then commit - https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-from-the-command-line/

Comment: Please read [a book on Git](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2).

Comment: Use appropriate `git add` and `git commit` commands. Be sure to check the files to be sure they are the versions that you wish to add. Also edit any conflicts.

Comment: Thank you guys , some good resources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to choose your local files over the remote files, do:

```
git checkout --ours wsgi.py
git checkout --ours .openshift/markers/README.md
git checkout --ours .openshift/cron/README.cron
git commit -a
```